# Git - How to Revert incorrect code between 2 push on master

Tags: git, github

Suppose I've working code in my master branch at PUSH A.

I've pushed some wrong code in my master, say PUSH B

Over my wrong commit, there is one more push. PUSH C

Now I want to revert my code, but keep the correct changes of PUSH C in the master.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git revert` command to revert any commit you don't want.

`git revert <commit id>`

Additionally, if there was a PR raised to merge "PUSH B" then you also get "revert" option in the merged PR, which will ease your work.

Let me know if this helps!